# How do I use VBA to add periods in tables?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the below code which adds periods to the body of a PPT slide:

```
Sub TitlePeriod()

On Error Resume Next

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim strTitle As String

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    If sld.Shapes.HasTitle = True Then 'check if there is a title
        strTitle = sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Else
        strTitle = ""
    End If
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        'add periods only if text of shape is not equal to title text.
        If strTitle <> shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text Then
             shp.TextFrame.TextRange.AddPeriods
        If shp.HasTable Then
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.AddPeriods
        End If
    End If
    Next shp
Next sld

End Sub
```

I am trying to add bit to the code that will add periods to tables within a slide as well

`If shp.HasTable Then
   shp.TextFrame.TextRange.AddPeriods`

When I run the code there are not errors, but there are no periods added within the table. Would love some advice or any tips on how to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would like to offer some advice.  When trying to figure out issues like this, it is best to try to examine the object in the locals window.  This way, you can search through the properties of the object (in this case, the shape object, shp, which happens to be a Table) and figure out which properties you need to modify to achieve your desired results.  No offense meant, but from your questions, it appears that you are new to VBA and found some of this code somewhere.

Also, the code was actually causing an error for me, as the Table shape did not have a textframe (although I only made a test table....perhaps yours actually had one).  I added a check for the textFrame.

For your specific question, a shape object with a table, has a Table property that needs to be used to add things to the cells.  The Table, in turn, has a Columns object which is a collection of columns.  You need to loop through all of the columns.  Each column is a collection of cells, so you need to loop through the cells.  Each cell has the textframe and textrange objects you are looking for, so you need to run the .AddPeriods method on these objects.

```
 Sub TitlePeriod()

     On Error Resume Next

     Dim sld As Slide
     Dim shp As Shape
     Dim strTitle As String
     Dim myTable As Table
     Dim myColumns As Columns
     Dim col As Column
     Dim myCell As Cell


     For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
          If sld.Shapes.HasTitle = True Then 'check if there is a title
                strTitle = sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
          Else
                strTitle = ""
          End If
          For Each shp In sld.Shapes
                'add periods only if text of shape is not equal to title text.
                 If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then 'check to make sure there is text in the shape
                      If strTitle <> shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text Then
                            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.AddPeriods
                      End If
                 End If

                 If shp.HasTable Then 'Check to see if shape is a table
                      Set myTable = shp.Table 'Get the table object of the shape
                      Set myColumns = myTable.Columns 'Get the columns of the table
                      For Each col In myColumns 'Loop through the columns
                            For Each myCell In col.Cells 'Loop through the cells in the column
                                       myCell.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.AddPeriods 'Add periods to the cell
                             Next myCell
                       Next col
                 End If
           Next shp
      Next sld

 End Sub
```